# unable to connect to docker redis on windows from outside the docker instance

Tags: docker, redis

I've followed answers on other questions here on SO and via google but still unable to connect.  Below is my attempt.  I appreciate any suggestions to get this working.

Note all the firewalls are disabled during this test.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -d --name myredis -p 6379:6379 redis
Unable to find image 'redis:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/redis
f5d23c7fed46: Pull complete
a4a5c04dafc1: Pull complete
605bafc84bc9: Pull complete
f07a4e35cd96: Pull complete
17944e5e3eb7: Pull complete
6f875a8605e0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:8888f6cd2509062a377e903e17777b4a6d59c92769f6807f034fa345da9eebcf
Status: Downloaded newer image for redis:latest
3f65a413985e513ef3e9a578b09a3c8729a214c767197d9e34268a38114e39c6
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
3f65a413985e        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   myredis
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' myredis
172.17.0.2
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec -it myredis redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

The above indicates (to me) that redis is running on the docker image and listening on port 6379 on both the docker image and host machine.  From another powershell, I run redis client for windows and it just hangs

```
PS D:\Program Files\Redis> ./redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> connect 172.17.0.2 6379
```

Comment: can you run redis in forground and check logs

Comment: The IP address from that `docker inspect` command is basically useless in many environments; I’d suggest never running it at all.  The `docker run -p` option should make it accessible via your host’s IP address on the standard port; if you just type `ping` at the end of your example connected to 127.0.0.1:6379 (from the console on the same physical host) I’d expect it to work.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks!  that worked like a charm ... now on to a real client.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker run -p` option publishes the service's port on the host's IP address, and from outside of Docker you can connect to that.  If you are specifically on the console of the same physical host running the container, you can use the special host name `localhost` or the matching special IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` to reach the container.  (If you're inside a container, though, `localhost` usually means "this container".)

In your final `redis-cli` command where it says it's connected to `127.0.0.1:6379`, you've already connected to the containerized Redis: you're done.

You never need the IP address returned by `docker inspect`, and it's unreachable in several very common setups; I would recommend never trying to look it up at all.  If you're on a different host, or you're using Docker for Mac or Docker Toolbox, you will be unable to reach the Docker-private IP addresses, for example.  The way you've done it with `docker run -p` is correct.